# Time complexity and Space complexity, how to account for space complexity

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o, complexity-theory, space

Show T(n) is O(n) and S(n) is O(n^2) for MakeMatrix, which creates a square matrix and sets only diagonal elements to zero.
(disregard time for malloc)

```
MakeMatrix(size):

A = malloc(size * size * sizeof(int))
for i from 0 to size -1
A[i,i] =0
return A
```

I think I understand why T(n) is linear O(n)  as there is only 1 for loop, but why would the space complexity be O(n^2)?

Comment: because you still have to store the whole matrix in memory so O(n^2).

Comment: Please use proper formatting... "MakeMatrix(size) A = malloc(sizesizesizeof(int)) for i from 0 to size -1 A[i,i] =0 return A" is quite unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate `size * size * sizeof(int)`. It seems to me quite obvious that size * size makes the space complexity `n^2`. Space complexity means how much memory do you need, based on size of input. Here it is `size * size`.

Answer (score 0):

The number of elements in a matrix of size *n* is *n<sup>2</sup>*.

If the size of int is 4 bytes, then in the malloc call you are carving out *size * size * 4* bytes. Hence the space requirement is quadratic.

Even though you are iterating over only *size* elements (i.e. the diagonal elements only), yet you have reserved the space for all *size<sup>2</sup>* elements.